# Haskell sqlite3 code

Tags: database, haskell, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out how to use the sqlite moduls for haskell. This is my basic code:

```
import Database.SQLite

firstTry str = do 
    conn <- openConnection $ "/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/umecore-hs/testdata/ume.umedb"
    statement <- return $ "select * from segments where label = :n ;"
    b <- execParamStatement conn statement [(":n", Text "First words")]
    closeConnection conn
```

Now, this does not compile (ghci):

```
sqlitetest.hs:6:9:
    No instance for (SQLiteResult a0)
      arising from a use of `execParamStatement'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      execParamStatement conn statement [(":n", Text "First words")]
    In the expression:
      do { conn <- openConnection
                   $ "/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/umecore-hs/testdata/ume.umedb";
           statement <- return $ "select * from segments where label = :n ;";
           execParamStatement conn statement [(":n", Text "First words")];
           closeConnection conn }
    In an equation for `firstTry':
        firstTry str
          = do { conn <- openConnection
                         $ "/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/umecore-hs/testdata/ume.umedb";
                 statement <- return $ "select * from segments where label = :n ;";
                 execParamStatement conn statement [(":n", Text "First words")];
                 .... }
```

Not sure what to do with that though. `execParamStatement_` works, but of course does not return anything, which makes it less useful for understanding how to get data out of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the type of `execParamStatement :: SQLiteResult a => SQLiteHandle -> String -> [(String,Value)] -> IO (Either String [[Row a]])`. It means the caller can choose any `a`, so far as it is an instance of `SQLiteResult`. However, since you aren't actually using `b` for anything, the compiler just assigns a type variable `a0` to it.

You need to specify the type (most likely you want `Value` for `a`), either through actually using the result of `execParamStatement` or with `execParamStatement conn statement [(":n", Text "First words")] :: IO (Either String [[Row Value]])`.

Comment: Thanks! Coming back to Haskell again after some time away, I forgot about the value of type signatures even (or especially) in short pieces of code designed for figuring out how something works.